Issue blacklisting folders in site's root directory using .htaccess
Context
I have several websites on my server, all of which are addon domains, and each website corresponds to an individual folder inside of the public_html folder. Let's say I have two websites:

sports.com (points to folder "sports")
quizzes.com (points to folder "quizzes")

When I go to sports.com, the content inside of the "sports" folder loads properly. However, when I type "sports.com/quizzes" as the URL, the website content from quizzes.com shows up as I am able to access that site's folder.
Basically, I'm able to access every website I have up through each individual site's URL.
I wasn't sure how to go about fixing this problem, but I eventually landed on using .htaccess to manually blacklist every folder name in public_html that I don't want the user to have access to (which is everything outside of the site's root folder — like the "sports" folder if I'm on sports.com).
Attempted Solution
I found this code, which was supposed to disallow users from accessing the "quizzes" folder if they are on sports.com:
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sports\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^quizzes/(.*)$ - [F,L]

I also found it in this format:
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sports\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/quizzes/
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

These solutions are supposed to check whether the host is sports.com, and if so, check the rest of the URL. If it contains "quizzes", it blocks the user from going to that folder.
Neither of these solutions worked. I tried adding it to the root of public_html as well as to each site's individual root folder ("sports" and "quizzes"). It didn't change the behavior at all. I have no idea why it's not working.
Note: this code is part of my larger block of .htaccess code (the following code is the public_html .htaccess code):
RewriteEngine on  

#redirect sports.com requests to sports folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?sports.com$  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sports/  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sports/$1  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?sports.com$  
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sports/index.php [L]

#code to blacklist "quizzes" directory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sports\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/quizzes/
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

#disallows files from being listed if there is no index file in directory
IndexIgnore *

Questions
Any ideas why it's not working or other ways I can try to find a solution to this problem?
Also, is it an issue if a user is able to traverse my folders in this way if the only folders they can access are folders of other public websites? The folders that are not supposed to be accessible already contain a "Forbidden access" error message.
Other Things Tried
I tried figuring out whether mod_rewrite was on, and I couldn't figure out how to do it. I used sudo a2enmod rewrite in the terminal through SSH, but it said that command didn't exist. I echoed out phpinfo(), but it didn't say anything about mod_rewrite. I also tried print_r(apache_get_modules());, and I got a 500 error. Additionally, I'm already able to rewrite the URLs of other pages on the website, so I would assume that means it's on.
I also tried clearing the cache and accessing the site in incognito mode, which didn't make a difference.

The proper answer is to set the DocumentRoot directive appropriately in each virtual host configuration. Is there some reason why you can't do that?

@TangentiallyPerpendicular I don't have access to that through my host. Apparently cPanel has the sites' document roots as public_html instead of their respective folders, so I'm trying to figure out how to change it in cPanel. I might just have to remove and re-add the domain in cPanel.
